# Difference between Gita Press Sankshipt version of Puranas with full version Puranas?

Tags: reference-request

I was looking for some Puranas and found that Gita Press have Sankshipt version of many Purana. I want to know what is difference with Full version. Do Sankshipt version contains all spiritual teachings ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between The Unabridged versions of Puranas and The Abridged (Sankshipta) versions of Puranas of Gita press is that the Abridged versions actually remove  chapters from their publications.

Let's take their Sankshipta Narada Purana For An Example. The third Paada of Narada Puraana contains chapters dedicated to Mantras for various dieties in the unabridged version. It includes Vaishnava, Shaiva, Shaakta and Even Ganapati(Ganesha) Mantra as shown [here](https://archive.org/details/narada-puran-part-3-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/page/n17/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

[image]

But In the Gita press version of the abridged Naarada puraana we see, that they have published the chapters only concerning Mahavishnu, Sita-Rama, Hanumana and Radha Krishna and skipped straight up to the fourth paada, thereby deleting all the Chapters concerning the Mantras of Devi, Shiva(Mahesa) as seen [here](https://archive.org/details/narada-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n9/mode/2up?view=theater).

[image]

The Raadha Krishna sahasranaama has been published, but  The Lalita sahasranaama present in the same purana has been removed.

Next, Let us take a look at the abridged version of Padma Puraana of Gita Press.

Paatala, Khanda. As seen from here, Gita press has only Published the Chapters upto the Narrative of King Mahiratha and describing meditation on Krishna and then skipped over to the next khanda as seen [here](https://archive.org/details/padma-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n13/mode/2up?view=theater).

[image]

In the [unabridged version of the same purana](https://archive.org/details/padma-puran-part-6-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/page/n15/mode/2up?view=theater), however we see that there are several chapters even after that which the abridged version has ommitted.

[image]

The Patala Khanda has been used only as an example. Readers, upon cross checking can find chapters omitted from other Khandas of the Padma purana as well.

This Post is not meant to be a criticism Of Gita Press btw. Casual readers who lack time to go through unabridged texts can very well read the abridged Purana Translations of Gita Press. However, I would not really recommend the abridged translations to sincere seekers.

Comment: Thanks. Can you compare Markandeya Puran. i have ordered that

Answer (score 1):

The word Sangshipt means a brief summary. Basically an abridged version.

So, the abridged version gives a summary, no quote unquote conversation just a brief from a 3rd person poibt of view, as sn example you can see in the [abridged version of Mahabharata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata?) and the full version is well, [a full version only](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan).

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..